# Get dynamic segment value

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember-cli and ember 2.

I've this route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('/', { path: '/:query' });
  this.route('qrcode-capture');
  this.route('item', { path: '/item/:name' });
});

export default Router;
```

But when I try to use `params.name` inside the `item.hbs` template I get undefined.

I've tried defining a route for `item` in this way:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    this.set('params', params);
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('params', this.get('params'));
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

But then, inside `params` i get `Object {name: null}` (even if the URL has the `:name` segment filled.

What am I doing wrong?

ps:

my `index` route looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('home');
  }
});
```

Comment: I put this code in an https://ember-twiddle.com and I see no issues.  This should work.  I would call the super before doing anything else, but still I don't see the issue.  Any other relevant code that may be tripping it up?

Comment: I've added my index route, maybe doing that changes something.. (the link-to is placed inside the `home` template)

Comment: Would you mind posting your entire Router.

Answer (score 1):

I've replaced `:name` with `:itemName` and now my params log returns `Object {name: null, itemName: 'test' }`

I guess `name` is somehow reserved by Ember then...